# Regex to remove line from css file

Tags: php, css, regex

I'm trying to remove include statements from a css file. So given a css file like

```
@import url("css1.css");
@import url("css2.css");
@import url("css3.css");
.myfirstclass {color:red}
```

after I run the command I want to be

```
.myfirstclass {color:red}
```

This is the command I am using but it isn't working. Is there a way to do this?

```
$css_file = preg_replace("/^@import url(.*)$/", "", $css_file);
```

Comment: Is every import in the css file terminated with a linebreak of some sort? Meaning, its not a .min'ified .css file?

Comment: The parentheses need \escaping else they are a capture group

Comment: Also, there might be whitespace before the @, and dont forget the semicolon... I'm not a wiz with regex patterns, so it would take me way too long to figure it out when i know a regexpert will pop in and solve this riddle in a flash! :)

Comment: You forgot `m` modifier `$css_file = preg_replace("/^\s*@import url.*/m", "", $css_file);  `

Comment: @AlexK The unescaped parentheses does not make the pattern fail, it just makes the pattern less literal.  It would effectively just create a capture group which contains the substring from `(` to `;`.  The faulty component is the `$`.  Either add the `m` flag or remove the `$`.  Or best, use revo's second method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caret `^` alongside dollar sign `$` mean asserting start of input string and end of it respectively unless `m` flag is set. You also need to check for spaces in beginning of line and match linebreaks at end:

```
$css_file = preg_replace("/^\s*@import url.*\R*/m", "", $css_file);  
                             ^               ^  ^
```

In case of working with minified CSS:

```
$css_file = preg_replace("/@import[^;]+;/", "", $css_file);
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked great. But please explain what the R is for. I can't find it mentioned in my searches for it. From your text, it seems it might refer to the line break but examples I found sayo to use \r\n.

Comment: `\R` means any kind of linebreaks which includes Unicode linebreaks as well.